# How to use number of activities in a single activities

Tags: android

Actually i want to use more than one activity at the same time but as i know if i switch to another activities the older one stops.But in some cases i want to use two or three activities concurrently.
So please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open More than one activity open concurrently then it is not possible 
If you open second activity then there are two possibility with first activity weather it can be

1) pause or

2) Finish

in android it is not possible for open more than one activity concurrently

but if you want some Business logic execute concurrently then you have different types of way like

1) Using Thread

2) Using Services

You can choose any of the option

If you want to load multiple activity within a Single Tab(means not at a time all open but at a time only one ) then the below Blog will help you

[See this blog](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Comment: Is it possible to use fragments.i want to know that if fragments is same as activity.If i will use fragments Can it serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Once you navigate to another activity, the previous get paused. If you want to get some code executed concurrently, you can look at [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).